# FAIL DEPLOY STRAPI TO HEROKU WITH MONGODB ATLAS

Tags: heroku, strapi

I am having this issue . There is somthing wrong with port or i dont know i cant figure out what.
Locally it works fine. when i start process as NODE_ENV=production , locally it works fine as well.
only when i deploy to heroku it fails with this issue

```
To https://git.heroku.com/strapi-kononov.git
   66ddbd0..01a2f73  master -> master
>> heroku logs --tail
2020-03-31T21:15:01.735944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-kononov.herokuapp.com request_id=54ec82eb-84bd-45c2-8b53-810ad8fb846f fwd="69.202.158.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-31T21:16:48.301287+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=strapi-kononov.herokuapp.com request_id=5b22b125-a906-445b-8c14-49346fb27699 fwd="69.202.158.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-31T21:16:48.610884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-kononov.herokuapp.com request_id=2042802e-14a9-49d0-b799-8b8a97709f09 fwd="69.202.158.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-31T21:20:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user toxasava@icloud.com
2020-03-31T21:22:36.267994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-31T21:22:36.065813+00:00 app[api]: Release v41 created by user toxasava@icloud.com
2020-03-31T21:22:36.065813+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 66ddbd0e by user toxasava@icloud.com
2020-03-31T21:22:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-31T21:23:17.612236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-03-31T21:23:19.949714+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:19.949731+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@0.1.0 start /app
2020-03-31T21:23:19.949732+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2020-03-31T21:23:19.949732+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.867550+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.870855+00:00 app[web.1]: Project information
2020-03-31T21:23:25.870957+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902884+00:00 app[web.1]: ┌────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902886+00:00 app[web.1]: │ Time               │ Tue Mar 31 2020 21:23:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated … │
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902888+00:00 app[web.1]: │ Launched in        │ 5318 ms                                          │
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902888+00:00 app[web.1]: │ Environment        │ production                                       │
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902888+00:00 app[web.1]: │ Process PID        │ 23                                               │
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902889+00:00 app[web.1]: │ Version            │ 3.0.0-beta.19.4 (node v13.11.0)                  │
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902889+00:00 app[web.1]: └────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
2020-03-31T21:23:25.902992+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903193+00:00 app[web.1]: Actions available
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903309+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903458+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome back!
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903564+00:00 app[web.1]: To manage your project , go to the administration panel at:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903703+00:00 app[web.1]: http://localhost:52586/admin
2020-03-31T21:23:25.903793+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.905494+00:00 app[web.1]: To access the server ⚡️, go to:
2020-03-31T21:23:25.905643+00:00 app[web.1]: http://localhost:52586
2020-03-31T21:23:25.905741+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-31T21:24:18.237298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-31T21:24:18.131083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-03-31T21:24:18.131083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-03-31T21:24:18.218744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sharing with your these two videos that deploy Strapi app on heroku - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd-xpaT0c48&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=2&t=0s and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHnRsZwFmR8&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=6

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I tried several setups and followed step by step the instructions on Strapi documentation, and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change the APP_ENV to "production" on heroku dashboard as well ?
[heroku dashboard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HuZw.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is your `server.json` config for production environment?

Below config works for me when the host is set as '0.0.0.0' and port set as '1337'

```
{
  "host": "${process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0'}",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 1337}",
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "path": "/dashboard",
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```